# C++ Возврат указателя на память, выделенную в теле функции

Tags: c++

Чтобы вернуть указатель на память, выделяемую в теле функции (при этом заранее не известно сколько памяти занимают данные), можно предоставить 2 функции: одна возвращает необходимый объём памяти, другая получает указатель на выделенную извне память и туда копирует данные. Но это не удобно, потому что нужно сделать 2 вызова и выделить память самостоятельно, а так же неэффективно, так как происходит ненужная операция копирования.

Ещё можно выделить память с помощью `GlobalAlloc` и вернуть указатель и размер выделенного блока памяти. Но это так же не удобно, поскольку придётся проследить за тем, чтобы в конце работы был вызван `GlobalFree`. Этот вариант можно усовершенствовать оборачивая указатель `HGLOBAL` в `unique_ptr`:  `std::unique_ptr<BYTE, HGLOBAL(_stdcall*)(HGLOBAL)>`; передавая в конструктор ссылку на `GlobalFree`. Конструкция конечно выглядит громоздко, да и сам по себе `unique_ptr` наложит некоторые ограничения.

А какие вы знаете решения данной задачи, лишённые недостатков?

Comment: Что-то вопрос какой-то непонятный и противоречащий сам себе. // «можно предоставить 2 функции» — что мешает сделать всё в одной функции? // «возвращает необходимый объём памяти» — так значит всё-таки **заранее известно** сколько памяти занимают данные? Что мешает выделить этот самый «необходимый объём памяти» и провести всю работу непосредственно в этом объёме без всяких копирований?

Comment: Ну возьмём такой пример из WinHTTP: для получения данных из тела запроса мы должны сначала вызвать `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable`, чтобы узнать сколько данных пришло, далее выделить память и передать указатель в `WinHttpReadData`. 2 вызова + самостоятельное выделение памяти + внутри `WinHttpReadData` выполнит копирование из своего внутреннего буфера в наш.

Comment: Так в чём вопрос — в проектировании своего API или в использовании чужого API? Упомянутый вами WinHTTP является вообще сишным API, а делать то же самое в C++ вас никто не заставляет

Comment: Вопрос в проектировании своего API. Могу ещё один демонстрационный пример накинуть: преобразование `HBITMAP` в массив байт, который можно в итоге записать в .BMP файл или передать по сети, 1 удобным вызовом. Передавая `HBITMAP` в функцию обработки мы не знаем сколько памяти в итоге займёт результат. Нужно сначала сделать вызов для получения количества памяти, создав внутри такой функции `PBITMAPINFO` и сохранив его для дальнейшего использования, и далее сделать второй вызов, уже для копирования данных в переданный буфер.

Comment: Не то чтобы эта всё представляет из себя проблему, но интересно возможно ли найти максимально удобную реализацию.

Comment: Но даже если рассматривать WinHTTP, то обратите внимание, что такой API позволяет обойтись без выделений памяти вообще — можно создать буфер фиксированного размера, например, даже в стеке и считывать данные в этот буфер по частям (в цикле) и обрабатывать тоже по частям (если задача позволяет). Если вы проектируете свой API и считаете, что для вашей задачи всегда выделять память это нормально, то брать пример с WinHTTP вам не стоит

Comment: Ну обычно при обработке HTTP запроса нужно прочитать данные целиком и представить непрерывным блоком памяти (например при обработке ответа в формате JSON). Да и разве `WinHttpReadData` не выполнит лишнее копирование из своего внутреннего буфера в переданный через параметр? Возможно пример с WinHTTP не очень удачный, но суть наверное демонстрирует. Хочется выделить память внутри функции и вернуть так, чтобы она не была высвобождена после завершения вызова.